# How to calculate the confidence interval of non-normal large volume data sample?

Tags: confidence-interval

There are tens of thousands of data, and the sample mean is 5.04, the sample standard deviation is 3.97, the skewness is 3.74, and the kurtosis is 23.721. How can we calculate confidence intervals for such **non-normal large volume data samples** to screen out outliers?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What do you mean by confidence intervals? A confidence interval is only meaningful with reference to an underlying parameter.

Comment: This question might be better for stats.stackexchange.com.